# Write a function that returns the name of the currency with the maximum value of the rate

Tags: python, function, python-requests

I have to write a function that returns the name of the currency (‘Name’ field) with the maximum value of the rate using the service https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/daily_json.js.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
import requests

class Rate:

    def __init__(self, format_='value'):
        self.format = format_

    def exchange_rates(self):
        self.r = requests.get('https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/daily_json.js')
        return self.r.json()['Valute']

    def make_format(self, currency):
        response = self.exchange_rates()

        if currency in response:
            if self.format == 'full':
                return response[currency]

            if self.format == 'value':
                return response[currency]['Value']

        return 'Error'

    def eur(self):
        return self.make_format('EUR')
    def usd(self):
        return self.make_format('USD')
    def brl(self):
        return self.make_format('BRL')

r = Rate(format_='value')
r.brl()  # 14.1581
r.eur()  # 88.1397
```

But I cannot figure out how to return the currency with the maximum value.

Comment: What does "maximum value of the rate" mean (what rate)? Which currencies, all of them or what?

Comment: Why do you create a class for this? Seems overkill...

Comment: @ martineau What does "maximum value of the rate" mean (what rate)? Which currencies, all of them or what?  - yes, from all currencies on the external site, I need to get one with the highest values

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you're creating a `class` to do this or exactly what you want, but if it's the `"Name"` with maximum `"Value"` of *all* the currencies, you could define a `max_rate()` class method as shown below:

```
from operator import itemgetter
import requests


class Rate:
    def __init__(self, format_='value'):
        self.format = format_

    def exchange_rates(self):
        self.r = requests.get('https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/daily_json.js')
        return self.r.json()['Valute']

    def max_rate(self):
        getter = itemgetter('Name', 'Value')
        rates = [getter(info) for info in self.exchange_rates().values()]
        return max(rates, key=itemgetter(1))  # Return Name, Value with max Value.


r = Rate()
print(r.max_rate())
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this

```
import requests

class Rate:

    def __init__(self, format_='value'):
        self.format = format_
    
    def exchange_rates(self):
        self.r = requests.get('https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/daily_json.js')
        return self.r.json()['Valute']
    
    def make_format(self, currency):
        response = self.exchange_rates()
        
        if currency in response:
            if self.format == 'full':
                return response[currency]
            
            if self.format == 'value':
                return response[currency]['Value']
        
        return 'Error'
    
    def eur(self):
        return self.make_format('EUR')
    def usd(self):
        return self.make_format('USD')
    def brl(self):
        return self.make_format('BRL')
    def max(self):
        
        x = self.brl()# 14.1581
        y = self.eur()# 88.1397
        z = self.usd()
        if max(x,y,z)==x:
            return "Brl"
        elif max(x,y,z)==y:
            return "EUR"
        else:
            return "USD"
r = Rate(format_='value')

x = r.brl()# 14.1581
y = r.eur()# 88.1397
z = r.usd()
Max = r.max()
print("Brl ",x)  
print("Eur ",y)
print("Usd ",z)
print("Maximum = ",Max)
```